# Looping through covariates in regression using R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, regression

I'm trying to run 96 regressions and save the results as 96 different objects. To complicate things, I want the subscript on one of the covariates in the model to also change 96 times. I've almost solved the problem but I've unfortunately hit a wall. The code so far is,

```
for(i in 1:96){

  assign(paste("z.out", i,sep=""), lm(rMonExp_EGM~ TE_i + Month2+Month3+Month4+Month5+Month6+Month7+Month8+Month9+
  Month10+Month11+Month12+Yrs_minus_2004 + 
  as.factor(LGA),data=Pokies))

}
```

This works on the object creation side (e.g. I have z.out1 - z.out96) but I can't seem to get the subscript on the covariate to change as well.

I have 96 variables called TE_1, TE_2 ... TE_96 in the dataset. As such, the subscript on TE_, the "i" needs to change to correspond to each of the objects I create. That is, z.out1 should hold the results from this model:

```
z.out1 <- lm(rMonExp_EGM~ TE_1 + Month2+Month3+Month4+Month5+Month6+Month7+Month8+Month9+
  Month10+Month11+Month12+Yrs_minus_2004 + as.factor(LGA),data=Pokies)
```

And z.out96 should be:

```
z.out96 <- lm(rMonExp_EGM~ TE_96+ Month2+Month3+Month4+Month5+Month6+Month7+Month8+Month9+
  Month10+Month11+Month12+Yrs_minus_2004 + as.factor(LGA),data=Pokies)
```

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm grateful for any tips/advice.

Comment: But apart from the programming problem, you should probably rethink or ask on CrossValidate about lm on a time series as individual factors. The result is definitively misleading or simply wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would put the results in a list and avoid the `for loop` and `assign` statements

You can use a combination of  `reformulate` and `update` to create your formula

```
orig_formula <- MonExp_EGM~ Month2+Month3+Month4+Month5+Month6+Month7+Month8+Month9+
 Month10+Month11+Month12+Yrs_minus_2004 + as.factor(LGA)


te_variables <- paste0('TE_', 1:96) 
# Or if you don't have a current version of R
# te_variables <- paste('TE', 1:96, sep = '_')  

 new_formula <- lapply(te_variables, function(x,orig = orig_formula) { 
    new <- reformulate(c(x,'.'))
    update(orig, new)})
 ## it works!    
new_formula[[1]]
## MonExp_EGM ~ TE_1 + Month2 + Month3 + Month4 + Month5 + Month6 + 
##   Month7 + Month8 + Month9 + Month10 + Month11 + Month12 + 
##   Yrs_minus_2004 + as.factor(LGA)
new_formula[[2]]
## MonExp_EGM ~ TE_2 + Month2 + Month3 + Month4 + Month5 + Month6 + 
## Month7 + Month8 + Month9 + Month10 + Month11 + Month12 + 
## Yrs_minus_2004 + as.factor(LGA)


models <- lapply(new_formula, lm, data = pokies)
```

There should now be 96 elements in the list `models`

You can name them to reflect your originally planned nnames

```
names(models) <- paste0('z.out', 1:96)
# or if you don't have a current version of R
# names(models) <-paste('z.out', 1:96 ,sep = '' )
```

and then access a single model by

```
 models$z.out5
```

etc

or create summaries of all of the models

```
 summaries <- lapply(models, summary)
```

etc....

```
 # just the coefficients
 coefficients <- lapply(models, coef)

 # the table with coefficient estimates and standard.errors

 coef_tables <- apply(summaries, '[[', 'coefficients')
```

Comment: thanks! This does the trick. Suppose I want to extract coefficients from the models, would it then be prudent to use a for loop? Example -

bumpkis <- matrix(nrow=96,ncol=1)
for (i in 1:96){
  bumpkis[i,] <- c(models$z.out(i)$coefficients[2])
  
}

This doesn't work unfortunately because I can't get the i to work. I think I'm missing something fundamental about loops.

Comment: No. See my examples in edited solution. For this kind of activity, loops will work, but an idiomatic R solution is to use `lapply`. Your use of the `i` in `models$z.out(i)` would be incorrect. Try `models[[paste('z.out',i,sep='')]]`. You won't be able to use `$`